# Noise with fender hot rod deluxe 112

Tags: amplifiers

I use a fender hot rod deluxe ampli but it makes a little noise like a metronome noise with 60 bpm.
(I put the link in order to describe the noise)

What could be possible reasons for this noise and how can I fix it ?

Comment: So, a video of something that is not the actual noise doesn't help much. Or really at all.

Comment: Wrist watch close to the pickups?

Comment: @ToddWilcox if you have a better proposition in order to describe it, all proposition are welcome ! :)

Comment: If you have a smart phone you could record the actual sound and upload some of the sound to any of a number of audio or video sharing sites and link that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an all tube design (I have the Blue Deluxe and I love it) and there are many things that could cause that. First I suggest you make sure that the sound is caused by the amp itself. Plug the amp into a wall outlet, don't plug any instruments or pedals into it, and turn it on. Turn all the knobs all the way down. Turn the master volume up (on the clean channel) and see if the noise appears. If not, turn up the clean volume knob and see if it appears. If not, lower both and do the same again on the gain and more gain channels. Finally, try turning up the reverb knob with the other volume knobs up. Note: **If you turn the master all the way up and turn up the reverb knob and then bump the amp, it will make a VERY loud noise. Don't bump it!** Turn the knobs back down to zero once you're confident that the noise is or isn't appearing.

If you do hear the noise while going through the above process, stop there and try to find a different power outlet as far away from the first one as possible and repeat the process. If you get the noise again, I would take it to an amp tech and have them look at it. If you take it to a tech, tell them exactly what knobs you have to turn up to make the noise appear. You could try buying all new tubes for it and changing them out, which you should probably do anyway if you haven't changed the tubes in more than a couple years. If you do that and the noise goes away then problem solved.

If you do not hear the noise when going through the above process, then it might not be the amp at all. You can try plugging in a cable to the input with no guitar and then repeat the test and see if you get the noise. If the noise only comes when you plug in a guitar (without any pedals) then there is probably something in your house that is putting out noise bursts that are being picked up by the guitar. Could be a wireless router or microwave or computer or anything electronic.

If it doesn't appear with just the guitar and amp, then try your pedals one by one. If you find a pedal that makes the noise, then great. Try changing from plug-in power to battery or change to battery if you use a power supply.

If the noise only appears when you have all your pedals plugged in together then there's some interaction between your pedals. Look at delay pedals and chorus, flanger, phaser, and other modulation effects as possible causes.

Comment: It's possible that signals from a wi-fi router could be picked up by the amp itself as well as by the guitar pickups. I've had that happen with a transistor amp. It took quite a while to track down the source, because the irregular low-volume "clicking" sounds actually sounded as if they were coming from somewhere outside the house, rather than from the loudspeakers! The fix was simply to move the router a few feet further away from the amp.

Comment: @alephzero Excellent point. I hope if that is a factor that moving the amp to a different outlet would make the difference. With a sound like this, I really doubt it's a problem with the amp since apparently it is very regular.

Comment: Thanks for your propositions and help. Unfortunately, it was not because of wi-fi router. I think it is better to take it to some technician, it has been 4 years that I use this ampli, maybe some cables inside became obselete.

Comment: If you haven't change the tubes in four years, I suggest you do that first. Buy a whole new set of tubes. There are many places you can buy sets for the HRD series. My personal favorite is https://www.eurotubes.com/store/pc/viewCategories.asp?idCategory=94 Changing a tube is a bit like changing a lightbulb.